# How to graph $\eta(t)=(t,|t|)$?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, graphing-functions

We are studying lines (I am not quite sure about the correct term in English and could not find any other term for this from googling so please correct me if I am wrong) in our calculus class right now and this might be a dumb question but I am having a hard time understanding how to draw graphs.

As an example, we were given $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $\gamma(t)=(\cos{t},\sin{t})$ and said that it graphs a unit circle. However, it is not quite clear to me how does this happen. Does $\gamma$ take values from $[0,2\pi]$ and I plug them in such as $\gamma(0)=(\cos{0},\sin{0})=(1,0)$, which is the starting point, and $\gamma(2\pi)=(\cos{2\pi},\sin{2\pi})=(1,0)$, which is the ending point? I mean $t\in [0,2\pi]$ right? And when I connect the starting and ending points I get an unit circle.

Another example which actually confused me was we were given $\eta: I\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $\eta(t)=(t,|t|)$ where $I=[-1,1]$. This was graphed as

[image]

but I don't know how we got that. If I plug in the values as I did on the first example, $\eta(-1)=(-1,|-1|)=(-1,1)$ and $\eta(1)=(1,|1|)=(1,1)$ but if it is now true that $(-1,1)$ is the starting point and $(1,1)$ the ending point, why the graph is not just a straight line between these points? How did we suddenly connected the points to the origin $(0,0)$?

Comment: We call these vectors, and you're working with vector functions.

Comment: These are "curves," which is probably not too far off from your translation of "lines."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the unit circle, if you know that $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1$, then it follows by deparameterizing the curve. Since $x = \cos t$, we have that $y^2 = \sin^2 t = 1-\cos^2 t = 1-x^2$, so the curve is given by $x^2+y^2 = 1$, or $y = \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Since $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are periodic with period $2\pi$, the graph for $t\in [0,2\pi]$ should be the entire circle, with the point $(1,0)$ being the starting and ending point.

For the absolute value, we do the same thing. We have $x = t$, so $y = |x|$ with $x\in [-1,1]$ Thus, we just graph the absolute value function only over the values $[-1,1]$ on the $x$-axis.

If you want to graph some parameterized curve like this without solving it algebraically (and sometimes you can't), you can simply plug in a bunch of values for $t$ in order and play connect-the-dots. The more $t$ values you use, the closer your approximation will be to the actual curve.